# Ntfs volume not mounting

Tags: xubuntu

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/sojan/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb3" "/media/sojan/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
```

Comment: Is that drive a windows partition? Even one that contains a windows OS?

Comment: Unclean usually means there are errors there, which maybe just it was/is used by a hibernated system (eg. windows was hibernated & some data went in the hibernate file instead of being fully-written to the file-system in a clean manner, this includes windows with *fast-boot* enabled), or you have errors in the file-system that need to be fixed first. Either way the message is there as a warning to prevent data loss.  You didn't provide release details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state)